# Node.js wth Istanbul code coverage

Tags: node.js, istanbul

I have installed node.js is there any help to work on node.js wth istanbul to do codecoverage

Comment: what is the prerequisite to work in Istanbul. I have installed node.js.

Comment: Have you read the docs, especially the [Getting Started Guide](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul#getting-started)?

Comment: Yes.  npm install -g istanbul this command is not working for me. I am using Windows 7. Kindly help me anything else prerequisite is there to complete this setup

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue right now - Windows Server 2008 x64, NodeJS. In my case I am trying to launch istanbul for Jasmine testing framework, because all tests are written for it. I recommend you to follow  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345025/node-js-test-coverage-issue-with-istanbul), so you will be able to launch your tests and see the coverage using [Mocha](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha) testing framework.